# How to fix Non-nullable instance when trying to get phones location

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, flutter-dependencies, google-geolocation

I'm trying to get the location of my phone with geolocation however the variable that stores location when you a press the button to get location has to be store as null at the beginning as I do not have the location of the phone yet however when I do that I get an error 'Non-nullable instance field 'currentposition' must be initialized' how to I fix this

this is my code

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String currentAddress = 'My Address';
  

  Position currentposition;
  void initState() {}

  Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {
    bool serviceEnabled; //check location service is enabled
    LocationPermission permission;

    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Please enable Your Location Service');
    }

    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Location permissions are denied');
      }
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg:
              'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    }

    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

    try {
      List<Placemark> placemarks =
          await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);

      Placemark place = placemarks[0];

      setState(() {
        currentposition = position;
        currentAddress =
            "${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode}, ${place.country}";
        print(currentposition);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    throw "";
  }
```

Comment: just use `?` for nullable like Position? currentposition; otherwise need to initialize when you declare

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a `variable` then you also have to `initialize` it by passing some `value` to it. But in any case you want to assign value `later` then you can `define` it as `late` making this change to your variable you can also make it `nullable` by using `?`

```
late Position currentposition; //late initialize but not null
```

and nullable with late

```
late Position? currentposition; //late initialize nullable
```